# The impact of pasting Google Tag Manager's snippets at the end of document instead?

Tags: tracking, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I'm using Google Tag Manger for the purpose using Google's Universal Analytics.

[Google Tag Manager's instruction suggests](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/quickstart) that the two snippets be pasted as close to the opening `<head>` tag as possible and immediately after the opening `<body>` tag, respectively.

How would my statistics of Universal Analytics be impacted if I paste the two snippets at the end of document (right before the closing `</body>` tag) instead?

Comment: If there are other scripts on the page they could be blocking or failing which potentially could stop your tracking code from functioning correctly i.e. not counting all visitors. If you are using more tags than GA then they would be affected too. Page loading timers would show wrong results etc. So it is highly recommended to follow the guidlines for implementing the gtm tag on your website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are other scripts on the page they could be blocking or failing which potentially could stop your tracking code from functioning correctly i.e. not counting all visitors. If you are using more tags than GA then they would be affected too. Page loading timers would show wrong results etc. So it is highly recommended to follow the guidlines for implementing the gtm tag on your website.